# Undocumented arguments in documentation object

Tags: r, package

So I'm trying to build my first package in R but I'm getting an error when I run check() that I'm not sure how to fix.

The error I'm getting is:

> Undocumented arguments in documentation object 'monthly.rainR'
>     ‘database’
>
> Functions with \usage entries need to have the appropriate \alias
>   entries, and all their arguments documented.
>   The \usage entries must correspond to syntactically valid R code.

I've had a look at Hadley's book and tried a few suggestions I found online... but none of solutions seemed to work

The roxygen2 document looks like this:

```
% Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand
% Please edit documentation in R/Simple.stats_rainR.R
\name{monthly.rainR}
\alias{monthly.rainR}
\title{Stand alone monthly rain plots:}
\usage{
monthly.rainR(database)
}
\value{
12 monthly average rainfall plots
}
\description{
Stand alone monthly rain plots:
}
\examples{
rain4 = load_rain()
monthly.rainR(rain4)
}
```

My monthly.rain() function looks like this:

```
#' Stand alone monthly rain plots:
#'
#' @return 12 monthly average rainfall plots
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' rain4 = load_rain()
#' monthly.rainR(rain4)

monthly.rainR = function(database){

  # Seperate by Month:
  # avm <- matrix(rain_month$rainfall[1:1932], ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
  avm <- matrix(database$r_month$rainfall[1:1932], ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
  # Compute annual average:
  avb <- seq(0,length = 161)
  for(y in 1:161){avb[y] = mean(avm[y,])}

  # Put monthly averages and annual average in a matrix:
  avmb = cbind(avm, avb)

  # Plot 12 panels on the same figure:
  plot.new()
  timeyr = database$r_year$year
  par(mar=c(1,1,1,1))
  par(mfrow = c(6,2)) # 4 rows & 3 cols
  par(mgp = c(2,1,0))

  for(i in 1:12){
    plot(timeyr, avmb[,i], type = "l", ylim = c(10,190),
         xlab = "Year", ylab = "Rainfall",
         main = paste("month is", i, split = ""))
    lm.rainR.monthly <- lm(avmb[,i] ~ timeyr)
    abline(lm.rainR.monthly, col="red")

  }

}
```

I'm a novice at writing packages, so I'm not sure what is going on here. Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: Before the `@return` you need to add `@param database` so that the argument has documentation.

Comment: Ah of course... I don't know how I missed that... Thanks

Answer (score 2):

After defining

```r
# ' @param
```

use

```r
# ' @return
```